# Image 100% below the img's original width

Tags: css, image, layout

I'm trying to set an `img` width to `100%` of it's container, the container changes size based on screen width, when the image is lower than its original size, i want to set the `img` width to 100%, however when the `image-container` is larger than the original width of the image, I want th position the image centrally inside of the container.

Any ideas?

```
.server-listing {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.server-listing .image {
    text-align: center;
}

.server-listing .image img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

My current CSS, pretty basic really, I need direction - thanks guys!

```
<?php foreach($this->model->data['servers'] as $server) { ?>
    <div class="server-listing">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="x.jpeg">
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

My phtml page

(NOTE: The image can be literally any size)

Comment: Please try max-width:100%; instead of width

Comment: Nailed it @YogeshSharma, thanks alot!

Comment: @YogeshSharma please write that as an answer! You beat me to it, so I will retract my answer if you add your own `:-)` (just tag me in a comment so I know to come back and do so!)

Comment: Glad you got it working. :) @Jackhardcastle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`max-width` is the CSS property you should be using!

```css
.server-listing {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: lime;
}
.server-listing .image {
    text-align: center;
}
.server-listing .image img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="server-listing">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500" />
    </div>
</div>
```

You probably have to enter fullscreen mode to really play with this!

Comment: Someone in the comment section beat you to it - nonetheless, thanks alot.

Comment: @Jackhardcastle asked the commenter to put an answer up to replace mine!

Comment: you did great job @gvee. in short time created demo :) upvote for your fast work

Answer (score 2):

Please try max-width:100%; instead of width.

The max-width property is used to set the maximum width of an element.

This prevents the value of the width property from becoming larger than max-width.

Comment: Dude, you need to expand this to be a fully formed answer. At the moment it's just a comment!

Comment: @gvee I hope now it's better :)

Answer (score -1):

See how it works for both small and large images:

```css
.server-listing {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100vw;
    height: auto;
}

.server-listing .image {
    text-align: center;  
    margin-bottom: 10px;  
    background-color: gray;  
}

.server-listing .image img {
    max-width: 95vw;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='server-listing'>
  <div class='image'>
    <img src='https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xap1/v/t1.0-1/c0.0.50.50/p50x50/10342461_799073063461766_6339462327156793350_n.jpg?oh=169a0d52644a444c2f723b1d1ec6c64b&oe=558BEB09&__gda__=1435700277_205a1d24a106c52496fe0e3eb20470e6' />
  </div>
<div>
<div class='server-listing'>
  <div class='image'>
    <img src='http://www.zastavki.com/pictures/1680x1050/2010/Animals_Cats_Cat_023761_.jpg' />
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you have to add margin and display:

```
.server-listing .image img
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        margin: 0px auto;
        display: block;
    }
```

Comment: Nope - someone else got it in the comments, width: 100% sets the img width to 100% of the parent container - however max-width would set the img width to a max width of it's 100%.

Thanks though!

Comment: Right, max-width it is (using skeleton, I already forgotten that :) ).